# Selecting Modal data to insert in to parent input field-Javascript, php, html

Tags: javascript, php, html

[Modal ID][1]
I am trying to insert selected item code into  dynamically inserted input box,but selected value is inserted only in 1 column.

I think i am making some mistake in array selection.
Here is my code:
For inserting dynamic rows:

```
var items = 0;
    function addItem() {
        items++;
 
        var html = "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
            html += "<td><input type='text'  id='item_code'  name='itemCode[]'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-flat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-item'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button></td>";
            // html += "<td></td>";
            html += "<td><input type='number' name='itemQuantity[]'></td>";
            html += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteRow(this);'>X</button></td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        var row = document.getElementById("item_tbody").insertRow();
        row.innerHTML = html;
};
```

For Selecting Item Code from Modal:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#select', function() {
  
     var item_code = $(this).data('itemcode');


    $('#item_code').val(item_code);
     $('#modal-item').modal('hide');
 
  })

});
```

html Div, where Item Code input box is inserted dynamically

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                     <table class="table table-display" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <label> Enter PR Item Codes (*Refer Item Table Button for Item Codes) </label>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Item Code</th>
                                        <th>Item Quantity</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody id="item_tbody"></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                     <button type="button" onclick="addItem();" class="btn btn-success">Add Item</button>
                     </div> 
          </div>
```

Modal Table: from which item code is selected and placed into Item Code input field

```
<table id="itemselect_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap"  cellspacing="0">  
                          <thead>  
                              <tr>  
                                   <!-- <th>Item id</th> -->
                                   <th>Item Code</th>
                                    <th>Item Desc. </th>
                                    <th>Action </th>

                              </tr>  
                          </thead>  
                          <?php  
                           $query ="select id as item_id, itemcode, itemdesc from itemcodes";
                                       
                           $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
          {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
               ?>
           <tr>
                    
                    <!-- <td> <?php echo $row['item_id']; ?></td> -->
                    <td> <?php echo $row['itemcode']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['itemdesc']; ?></td>
                    <td> <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" id="select" data-id="<?php echo $row['item_id'] ?>" data-itemcode="<?php echo $row['itemcode'] ?>" > <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Select</button></td>

          </tr>
           <?php 
               }
          }
           else {
              echo "No Record Found";
           }
          ?>
            </table>        

 </body>
```

Thanks for help in advance.